# 2d np array to 3d np array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm having a 2D np.array, and i have to visualise it. I already have a colormap function, so the last thing i have to do is to replace each value of the array with 3 another values, which are standing for RGB.

colormap function:

```
def colormapHLS(a: float):
    h, l, s = 0, 0, 0
    if a < 0:
        h = 2 / 3
        l = 0
        s = 1
    elif 0 < a <= 1 / 3:
        h = 2 / 3
        l = 0.5 * (a * 3)
        s = 1
    elif 1 / 3 < a <= 2 / 3:
        h = 2 / 3 - ((2 / 3) * ((a - 1 / 3) * 3))
        l = 0.5
        s = 1
    elif 2 / 3 < a <= 1:
        h = 0
        l = 0.5 + 0.5 * ((a - 2 / 3) * 3)
        s = 1
    elif a > 1:
        h = 0
        l = 1
        s = 1
    return h, l, s
```

and main code:

```
# ...
trans_func = lambda x: colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*colormapHLS(x))

draw_buff -= numpy.min(draw_buff)
draw_buff /= numpy.max(draw_buff)
print(draw_buff.shape)
colored_draw_buff = numpy.zeros((*draw_buff.shape, 3))
print(colored_draw_buff.shape)
for y in range(draw_buff.shape[0]):
    for x in range(draw_buff.shape[1]):
        cur = trans_func(draw_buff[y][x])
        for z in range(3):
            colored_draw_buff[y][x][z] = cur[z]

colored_draw_buff *= 255
# ...
```

*draw buff shape is (x, y)*

So, it actualy works, but it is too slow. I think there is a much faster way

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the question refers to `draw_buff` as an array, but it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
        self.draw_buff = self.draw_buff.reshape(x*y)

        self.draw_buff -= numpy.min(self.draw_buff)
        self.draw_buff /= numpy.max(self.draw_buff)

        self.draw_buff = numpy.array(trans_func(self.draw_buff))
        self.draw_buff *= 255
        self.draw_buff = self.draw_buff.swapaxes(0,1)
        self.draw_buff = self.draw_buff.reshape((y,x,3))
```

swap axes + reshapes are doing the job

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).